# CSS: Flexlayout left and right columns

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to use a flex layout to position control elements on my website. In the original example I have a toolbar above which is also part of the flex-container, but the issue is the same as in this example:

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.flex-container > div {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 20px;
  margin: 10px;
  line-height: 20px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="flex-container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div style="align-self: flex-end;">3</div>  
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, the divs within the flex-container are aligned beneath each other with one off to the right side. My goal is to get `3` to ignore the items on the left when calculating vertical offset, and thus end up parallel to `1`.
I'm aware of how I could do this with absolute positioning, but I'd like to use a flex layout - though if there's a neat solution with nested flex-layouts, it might work aswell.

Comment: you want it to work for this particular case or there is a more generic case behind

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
    width: 30px;
  height: 30px;

}
.flex-container-2 {
  display: flex;
    width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

.flex-element {
  width: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="flex-container-2">

<div class="flex-container flex-element" >

  <div class="flex-element">1</div>
  <div class="flex-element">2</div>
  </div> 
<div class="flex-element" style="">3</div> 

</div>

</body>
</html>
```